# What is the difference between cretino, stupido, imbecille, idiota?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What is the difference between cretino, stupido, imbecille, idiota?

It's not clear to me which ones are related to actual intelligence, vs displayed intelligence, and in general the other connotations.

I do not refer to the insults that do not follow any specific rule, but to the proper meaning.

From Treccani I see [imbecille](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/imbecille/), [idiota](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/idiota/), [stupido](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stupido/), [cretino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cretino/).

It seems to me that imbecille and idiota are the ones that actually refer to reduced mental abilities, with stupido being an intermediate term and cretino the least strong one, referred more to the behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I personally doubt there's any nuance (beyond the different etymological origins, of course), but let's see what our users answer.

Comment: Not an answer, but rather a pointer: most of what you might desire about the nuances of quasi-synonyms can be found in Niccolò Tommaseo's _Dizionario dei sinonimi della lingua italiana_. Tommaseo was a 19th-century writer and lexicographer with a wonderful sensitivity to the nuances of Italian words. You can find it (legally) scanned [here](https://archive.org/details/dizionariodeisin00tommuoft/) and, for instance, on pp. 514–5 you can find a discussion of _stupido_, _imbecille_ and other related words.

Comment: _Idiota_ and _cretino_ are covered in other pages, since they are quite farther from the other two words: _idiota_ originally meant someone who was extraneous to the community, and hence ignorant of other people's way, while _cretino_ used to be a medical term.

Comment: Among the words in the same semantic neighbourhood, the two other, non-vulgar, more frequent one today are _sciocco_ and _scemo_.

Answer (score 2):

In a newspaper article by L'Espresso named [*L'idiota di successo*](http://espresso.repubblica.it/visioni/cultura/2009/05/05/news/l-idiota-di-successo-1.13402) there's an interview to professor Umberto Eco, who dedicated a chapter of one of his books to idiocy, and about that he says:

> Umberto Eco 
>  **Ho fatto una distinzione, in uno dei miei libri, fra
>   l'imbecille, il cretino e lo stupido**. **Il cretino** non ci interessa. È
>   quello che porta il cucchiaio verso la fronte anziché puntare alla
>   bocca; è quello che non capisce quello che gli dici. Il suo caso è
>   semplice. **L'imbecillità**, invece è una qualità sociale e, per quel che
>   mi riguarda, puoi anche chiamarla diversamente visto che per alcuni
>   'stupido' e 'imbecille' sono la stessa cosa. **L'imbecille è colui che
>   in un certo momento dirà esattamente quello che non dovrebbe dire.** È
>   autore di gaffe involontarie. **Lo stupido** invece è diverso; il suo
>   deficit non è sociale ma logico. A prima vista sembra che ragioni in
>   modo corretto; è difficile accorgersi immediatamente che non è così.
>   Per questo è pericoloso. (...) Ti faccio un esempio. Lo stupido dirà:
>   'Tutti gli abitanti del Pireo sono ateniesi. Tutti gli ateniesi sono
>   greci. Quindi tutti i greci sono abitanti del Pireo'. Ti viene il
>   sospetto che qualcosa non funzioni perché sai che ci sono dei greci di
>   Sparta, per esempio. Ma non sai spiegare subito dove e perché si è
>   sbagliato. Dovresti conoscere le regole della logica formale. Ecco,
>   credo che dovremo occuparci specificamente dello stupido.
>
> Jean-Claude Carrière  Per me lo stupido non si accontenta di
>   sbagliare. Afferma chiaro e forte il suo errore, lo proclama, vuole
>   che tutti lo sentano.

So resuming, according to professor Eco's point of view:

- a *cretino* is someone who has some mental deficiency;
- an *imbecille* is who in a certain moment will exactly say something he shouldn't;
- a *stupido* is different: he hasn't a social deficiency but a logical one. At first sight his way of thinking seems to be correct, and it is very difficult to immediatly realize he's wrong. For this reason is dangerous.

Having said that I think in everyday speaking they are used quite interchangeably.

Comment: With all due respect to Eco, I'm not 100% convinced that this interpretation is widespread among Italian speakers.

Comment: I am Italian, and for insulting I use any of them with same meaning. However, cretino also has a proper medical meaning

Comment: I also wanted to comment that cretinismo was (is?) a medical condition. It fits anyway into the Eco's description that should be taken for what is. I totally agree with Eco but as other said the terms are used almost interchangeably.